# Stability in partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-theory

I have the following PDE, with parameters $a$ and $b$:

$$
\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left( a c + b \frac{\partial c}{\partial z}\right)
$$
with, for now, just one boundary condition
$$
\left.\left( a c + b \frac{\partial c}{\partial z}\right)\right|_{z=0} = 0
$$

I'm solving this PDE numerically using FD. I'm implementing another boundary condition when solving it numerically:
$$
c = 0 ~ \text{at} ~ z=H
$$
where $H\gg h$. The initial condition is a linear profile with negative gradient between $0$ and $h$ (i.e. $c=0$ at $z=h$ and $c=c_b$ at $z=0$)

For certain relation between the parameters $a$ and $b$ I obtain the transient solution.

$$
c(z) = A ~\text{exp}\left(\frac{-az}{b} \right)
$$

I cannot use the boundary condition I implemented in the numerical solution to obtain the constant $A$ because $c$ is never $0$ in the steady-state solution. However, in the numerical solution, I can get a steady state solution for certain values of $a$ and $b$, whereas for other values, the solution grows indefinitely (probably because of the indefinition of the constant A). Why is this happening? What are the conditions for stability or instability? I know I could just set an additional boundary condition and make it stable, I just want to know why the numerical scheme is obtaining the steady-state solution for certain values of $a$ and $b$. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.. Your boundary conditions are

$c_{z} (0,t) = \frac{-ac}{b}$

and

$c (H,t) = 0$

yeah?

Comment: Yeah. The first one with $c$ in the r.h.s. evaluated at $0$ as well.